# Could someone explain this step in a proof?

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin PMA p.222 (Inverse function theorem)

Let $E$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function.

Let $a\in E$ and assume that $f'(a)$ is invertible.

Define $A=f'(a)$.

Define $\phi(x)=x+A^{-1}(y-f(x)) \forall x\in E$ where $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have shown that $\phi$ is a contraction map.

It's written in the text that there exists at most one fixed point in $U$. How so?

Since $U$ is not closed and $\phi$ may range outside of $U$, one cannot apply Banach-fixedpoint theorem here. Why there is at most one fixed point for $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contractions have at most one fixed point: suppose $x,y$ are fixed by a contraction $f$. So $\operatorname{dist}(x,y)=\operatorname{dist}(f(x),f(y))<k \operatorname{dist}(x,y)$, with $0<k<1$, which is a contradiction unless $x=y$.